# Docker - Supervisor in Ubuntu throws ENOEXEC error

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, supervisord

I have a running Ubuntu Docker container that has python3.7, mongodb and supervisor installed. When I try to run my python scripts via the supervisor service it throws me the following error:

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /data/code/venvs/cleverInvest/bin/python: ENOEXEC
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

supervisor.conf

```
[supervisord]
;logfile=/var/app/logs/ ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=5           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=debug                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=true                ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[program:mongod]
;command=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
command=/usr/bin/mongod
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true
user=mongodb
priority=100

[program:server]
priority=10
;directory=/data/code/
;command=python3 server.py
command=/data/code/venvs/cleverInvest/bin/python /data/code/server.py
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:cleverinvest]
priority=10
;directory=/data/code/
command=/data/code/venvs/cleverInvest/bin/python /data/code/main.py
;command=python3 main.py
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I tried already to add a `!#/bin/sh` to the python file, or giving them a 777 rule. Nothing seems to help.

Here my Dockerfile

```
FROM       ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Docker

# Update apt-get sources AND install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt install -y gnupg2
RUN gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F3B1AA8B

# Installation:
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

RUN apt-get install -y python3.7
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
#Mongodb
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
RUN apt-add-repository 'deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse'

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org

# Supervisor for starting multiple process in Docker
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor && \
  mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor && \
  mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d

ADD supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.conf

# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

RUN chmod 777 /data/db

# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/code
RUN chmod 777 /data/code

RUN mongod --version

#RUN mongod --dbpath /data/db --fork --logpath /data/db/log

# COPY cleverInvest Code to Container
COPY dev /data/code

# Installing pip for python modules
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

# Install modules
WORKDIR /data/code/
RUN chmod +x -R *.py
RUN chmod 777 -R *
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip3 freeze

EXPOSE 80 27017

# Set /usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"]

#ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Usual practice is to run these in separate containers: you don’t want to accidentally delete your database just because you need to restart your application with a newer code base.

Comment: I know. but for this time I need it with 1 container... Nobody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by myself and I wanted to write my solution in case somebody else has the same problem.

I simply changed the method I started my python script by using the global installed python version and not via th virtualenv.
So my supervisor.conf file looks now like this:

```
[supervisord]
;logfile=/var/app/logs/ ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=5           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=debug                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=true                ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[program:mongod]
;command=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
command=/usr/bin/mongod
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true
user=mongodb
priority=100

[program:server]
priority=10
directory=/data/code/
command=python3 server.py
;command=/data/code/venvs/cleverInvest/bin/python /data/code/server.py
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:cleverinvest]
priority=10
directory=/data/code/
command=python3 main.py
;command=/data/code/venvs/cleverInvest/bin/python /data/code/main.py
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I also had a syntaxerror in my script file. After correcting them, it worked.